# How to automatically link all Flask buttons and links with the same IP address

Tags: flask

When I create a Flask website, the index has the following address: `127.0.0.1` which is the localhost. Another page such as contacts has this address: `127.0.0.1/contacts`.

When I deploy the website I have to change all the IP address in all the pages for all the buttons. Is there a better way?

I tried to use this:
Instead of `href = '127.0.0.1/contacts'`
I used `href = "url_for('templates', filename='contacts.html')"`

But it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to do `<a href='/contacts/'>Contacts</a>` and it will automatically reference the function "contacts" as defined in your .py file. You only have to use the full IP/domain if you're linking to an external site. I've never had a problem using the method above.

Comment: Thank you so much. So when you are linking to an external website, you still have to do `50.0.0.10/contacts` right ?

Comment: That is correct, all external sites will require either the full IP or the domain name, the internal pages can be linked as shown above.